# Sql Loader control file( DATE DATATYPE)

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'file.txt'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE SOURCE_TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
merchant_no   INTEGER  EXTERNAL(7),
MCHTYP        char(1),
ACC_BPAC_TYP  char(3),
ACC_DT_EFF    DATE "DD/MM/YYYY",
DT_EFF        DATE "DD/MM/YYYY",
ACC_SORT_CD   INTEGER  EXTERNAL(9),
ACC_ACCTNO    INTEGER  EXTERNAL(9),
DT_IF         DATE "DD/MM/YYYY",
PURGE_IND     char(1)
)
```

The problem is, Sql Loader is terminated on 'ACC_SORT_CD'.
I am facing the problem in every column after specifying DATE datatype.
It is not able to read the column which is coming after DATE datatype.

```
Insert option in effect for this table: TRUNCATE
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
MCHNO                          FIRST       7              CHARACTER            
Terminator string : '|'
MCHTYP                         NEXT        1              CHARACTER            
Terminator string : '|'
ACC_BPAC_TYP                   NEXT        3              CHARACTER            
Terminator string : '|'
ACC_DT_EFF                     NEXT        *              DATE DD/MM/YYYY      
Terminator string : '|'
DT_EFF                         NEXT        *              DATE DD/MM/YYYY      
Terminator string : '|'
ACC_SORT_CD                    NEXT        9              CHARACTER            
Terminator string : '|'
ACC_ACCTNO                     NEXT        9              CHARACTER            
Terminator string : '|'
DT_IF                          NEXT        *              DATE DD/MM/YYYY      
Terminator string : '|'
PURGE_IND                      NEXT        1              CHARACTER            
Terminator string : '|'

SQL*Loader-466: Column ACC_SORT_CD does not exist in table SOURCE_TABLE.
```

I have tried with another file as well but same problem is present.
Please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Can you add the table structure or DDL for `SOURCE_TABLE` to the question?

Comment: Perhaps the error message: `SQL*Loader-466: Column ACC_SORT_CD does not exist in table SOURCE_TABLE` is important. As @AlexPoole notes, we need to see the DDL for the table, and in addition an example of the data in the input file would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the obvious "the column isn't there": I usually **only** supply a data type for date columns (to specify the format). For all other data types, SQL*Loader usually does a good job converting that by itself. So you might try without specifying the other types.

Comment: Are you sure the log file is from the same control file?  The control file shows the first field should match the column named "merchant_no" but the log file has the error on a column named "MCHNO". Something is out of sync.  Check paths in your sqlldr command line perhaps?